# How to write a test for a solution of producer-consumer problem_?

Tags: .net, multithreading, algorithm, unit-testing, producer-consumer

As an excercise I want to implement a solution to the producer-consumer problem. Let's say I'll have an array int[] buffer and two methods Produce() and Consume() that will simulate the producer and customer, respectively, and one "Execute" method to call both method asynchronously.

It's probably to test whether the implementation will not result in a deadlock, just make Produce and Consume repeat for a large number of time (like 1 million), make Execute wait for these two methods to finish, and then (in my unit test) just make sure the call returns after certain time (maybe 1 minute). But how to test whether there is no race condition or data corruption in the implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Deadlock is not the only thing you should check for.  Deadlock is always quickly detected - your app stops. Lost or duplicated messages are more dangerous and insidious - a duped message may cause an app crash much later than when the dup occurred and, most likely, in a different module/thread/block than where the dup happened.  Such a bug is an absolute nightmare.

When testing queue classes, I create a 'Message' class with an internal random array[256] member and a checksum.  I initially create 10000 of these Messages, 'totalChecksum' their individual checksums and push pointers to them onto a 'pool' queue. Multiple producers, (I usually use 32), pop *Message instances from the pool queue and push them onto another 'comms' queue.  Multiple consumers, (I usually use 16) pop *Message instances from the comms queue and push them back onto the pool queue.

After 5 minutes of warming up the room, a simple GUI forms timer halts the producers by setting a volatile boolean that tells the producers to wait on a manualResetEvent. A Sleep(500) later, all 10000 messages should be back in the pool queue and the GUI checks that the pool queue count is 10000, pops 10000 messages in a loop, totalChecksumming them, pushing back on and finally comparing with the initial totalChecksum.  If this passes, the boolean is reset and the MRE signaled to make the producers run again.

I run this test overnight, repeatedly.  If there are ever any failures, the queue is not fit for purpose.